# Play a remote MOV in a UiWebView

Tags: ios, video, uiwebview, quicktime

I have a rather complex application that mostly works in a UiWebView. I would like to autoplay a MOV file from a URL full screen. My problem is that when I link to the MOV file the play icon is crossed out or video loads but does not play. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are you embedding the video in html? What does your html look like?

If you're using html5  note that auto play is not permitted.

I would recommend getting things working first using a video you know if of the correct format/codec type, then when that works switch your video.
You can download a set of supported reference videos from Apples web site.
Or use this to ensure your video is of the correct format:

http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/

Also you might want to read this:

http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Thanks. My plan was to directly link to the video file and have the iOS Media Player taking over but I guess this does not work then.

Comment: What do you mean by take over? If you put <video> in the html page then when the user clicks on the video the media player will launch and play the video (it can launch entirely and take over the screen, or play inline depending on what you want).